Setting a Cookie for multiple subdomains
I am currently facing a little challenge. I have a FastAPI Backend with a Mongo Database and two Angular Frontends. Both Frontends are communicating with the same Backend since both applications use parts of the same business logic.
Now, the problem is that if I login in one Frontend I am also automatically logged in in the other Frontend. I want to prevent that and I figured that I can set the domain as a parameter in the set_cookie method provided by FastAPI/Starlette. Both applications use different subdomains e.g. application1.foobar.com and application2.foobar.com.
My questions now are: If i run both Frontend applications at the same time then how can the Backend find out from what source/domain the request is coming from? Would setting the domain parameter in the set_cookie method even fix my problem?
The docs for FastAPI and Starlette are pretty vague and don't go much into detail on what these parameters are for. I also couldn't find a real world example that shows how this feature would be best implemented.
Thanks in advance! :)

The cookie is associated with the domain that the request is sent to, not from. So the back-end has to be running on both subdomains. Then it can use request.url to find out which domain the request was sent to.
